# Dynamically display tables in Windows phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am facing an issue with displaying dynamic tables. Basically, I am reading a list of tables from server and I need to display them in order. Each table has a header and a number of columns and rows which will be known at runtime. The problem is that each table can have an arbitrary number of columns and rows and I need to accommodate that in xaml. Any ideas how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a grid for each table, and set the rows/columns in codebehind with `grid.RowDefinitions.Add(...)`

Comment: I am looking for a solution via databinding, is that possible?

Comment: Yes, you should make a new "Table" control (which just wraps a grid) with two DependencyProperties, "NumRows" and "NumColumns" -- add change handlers to those DP's which internally modify the RowDefinitions/ColumnDefinitions collections.

Comment: concerns: 1) Those two dependency properties will deal with the number of columns and rows but how about the data itself, how shall I bind it. 2) Can you please show me this in code? Thanks

Comment: Add another binding for the data, and add it into the table as needed. I may do a sample when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can bind data dynamically When response came from server.for more information you can download sample provided in MSDN PeopleHub or PhotoHUb sample application that how to bind data.

Comment: I have seen PeopleHub example. The issue is that I don't know the nature of data beforehand so I can prepare data template for example. One time, I may receive a table with 2 columns and 3 rows containing data about something and the next time I may receive something else with 3 columns and 4 rows. It is dynamic.

Comment: so create Data template in .cs file not used static Data template in .Xaml file!!!!!!

Comment: if I am creating data template for each list dynamically, why not just populate the results in code behind without any binding? I am trying to find an elegant solution that deals with my situation using binding.